# How do I solve this RabbitMQ REST call 415 response issue?

Tags: rabbitmq, httpclient, resttemplate

In the code I inherited there is a REST call that sets up user permissions for a virtual host in a rabbitmq installation. On my developer box I have latest RabbitMQ server installed, 3.7.7. The client software uses a Spring RestTemplate to query the host. It generates a PUT request to http://localhost:15672/api/permissions/myhost/administrator with a payload of

```
{"read":".*","write":".*","configure":".*"}
```

and an HTTP header `Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8`

This all looks reasonable to me - but the response is

```
HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
```

This code is years old, and I suspect it is my RabbitMQ installation that is too new for it, but I'd like to rather make the code future-proof than to install an RabbitMQ from 2015 ...

I have googled extensively on this issue but all I found was some bug about doubled headers in the rabbitmq client software that is not in use here. I traced it into apache httpclient classes and there is nothing on the sender side that smells.

Any suggestions what is wrong?

Comment: Rather than just post snippets of the HTTP request, please post the *entire* request and reply. Also, note that the RabbitMQ team monitors [the `rabbitmq-users` mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users).

Comment: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/rabbitmq-users/hfhE0pAcTlY/discussion

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the Apache HttpClient was adding a second content-type header to the message, caused the rejection on RabbitMQ Management plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, content type should not be applied

```
curl -s -i -u guest:guest -H "content-type: application/json" -H "content-type: application/json"  -X POST --data '{"properties":{"delivery_mode":2},"routing_key":"program.*","payload":"{\"id\":\"123456\"}","payload_encoding":"string"}'  'http://127.0.0.1:15672/api/exchanges/%2F/my-exchange/publish'
```

return HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type

Without content-type or just one :

```
curl -s -i -u guest:guest -H "content-type: application/json"  -X POST --data '{"properties":{"delivery_mode":2},"routing_key":"program.*","payload":"{\"id\":\"123456\"}","payload_encoding":"string"}'  'http://127.0.0.1:15672/api/exchanges/%2F/my-exchange/publish'
```

> return HTTP/1.1 200 OK